# Transfer from SQL Server 2005 to 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I use an intranet tool that has a database  created using VS 2005(UI) and SQL Server 2005 and it was working just fine on windows server 2003.

Now I have transferred the database to a Windows 2008 Server which has SQL Server 2012 installed. I changed the connection string, reference assemblies and debugged using visual studio, It works perfect( I am able to login and access the database ). But When I try to do the same in IE, I get userid incorrect error on the login page(first page of UI).

I do not get any connection errors or user errors from the server. The target framework was 2.0 on the previous version but I had to change it to 4.0 in here because the new environment didn't like 2.0. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the connection strings? Are you using impersonation?

Comment: Do the same in IE?  Do you mean run your web application on IIs?  Also, if you are getting an error why wouldn't you post the error so we can see it.  Just saying there is an error is basically useless -- you want us to guess?  OK, I'll guess -- give the service account that runs IIs rights on SQL Server.

Comment: c.ConnectionString = "Data Source=CAM-SQL-NODE2;Initial Catalog=RecIT;Integrated Security=FALSE;User ID=user;Password=12345678;"

Comment: yes I mean running the web application on IIS and As I said earlier I do not get an error. If I get an error I could post it. The only error I get it is the one I set up for userid/password incorrect error on the login page. And I don't know the service account that runs IIS rights, Sorry I am a newbee.

Comment: Hi, could you please post the error message?

Comment: Hi Ademar, I dont get an error message to post and I dont use impersonation.

Comment: Please check the application pool, account settings of your intranet site.  The reason of your issue might be because access issues. Can you also give us what the Event Viewer log is saying?